# Angular2 integration to core file system and node.js libraries

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I am studying Angular2, Typescript and reactive programming.
I wrote a simple Typescript application on NodeJs which monitors a directory for changes (core OS and file system). In a single file.
Here it is https://github.com/maroshi/nodejs-directory-monitor/blob/master/app.ts

Now I want to add an interactive GUI to it using Angular2.
I want to integrate my directory monitor as service to Angular2 application.

The questions.

1. Is it architecturally safe/correct to allow Angular2 application to access the file system and OS (assuming it is a fancy NodeJs server)?
2. How to integrate NodeJs `fs` utility library into an Angular2 application.

I am using the Angular2 quickstart template from https://github.com/angular/quickstart.

I modified the `app.component.ts`

```
import  * as FileSystem  from 'fs';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
        <p>Some FileSystem info: {{dirInfo}}</p>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
private proccesInfo: string;
    ngOnInit(){
        let tmpString: string[] = FileSystem.readdirSync('/home');
        this.dirInfo = tmpString != null ? tmpString[0] : 'undefined';
    }
}
```

This compiles well but fails to bootstrap with the following errors:

```
GET XHR http://localhost:3000/fs 404 (Not Found)

Error: patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_moduleszone.js/dist/zone.js:769:27
    Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
    Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/fs as "fs" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
```

Please advise about this exploration.

Note the tsconfig.json is the default tsconfig.json from the link above. Compiling for NodeJs
`"module": "commonjs",`

Thanks 
Joy and happiness

Dudi

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: I have to check again with Angular 4...